# Routes filtering by Language and/or category

Tags: python, flask, routes

I'm building a StumbleUpon like application which the content has to be filtered by language and category. I have two simple routes for each, language and category, but I would like to know if it's possible to have both in one simple router declaration. To not get confused I'm using Peewee as the ORM.

Here are the routes I've already defined:

```
@app.route("/<language>")
def languages(language):
    links = []

    for contenido in models.Post.select().where(models.Post.language**language):
        links.append(contenido.content)

    iframe = random.choice(links)
    return render_template('language.html', iframe=iframe, language=language)


@app.route("/<category>")
def categories(category):
    links = []

    for contenido in models.Post.select().where(models.Post.category**category):
        links.append(contenido.content)

    iframe = random.choice(links)
    return render_template('category.html', iframe=iframe, category=category)
```

models.py

```
class Post(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    user = ForeignKeyField(
        rel_model=User,
        related_name='posts'
    )
    language = TextField()
    category = TextField()
    content = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
```

What I'm trying to do is to have a relation on language and/or categories in the navigation feature. Is it possible to create something like this? I'm actually really lost trying to accomplish something like this. At the time I have something that could look a little what I'm trying to do, here is the snippet:

```
@app.route("/<language>/<category>")
def mixin(language, category):
    language_links = []
    category_links = []

    for contenido in models.Post.select().where(models.Post.language**language):
        language_links.append(contenido.content)

    for contenido in models.Post.select().where(models.Post.category**category):
        category_links.append(contenido.content)


    if category_links == []:
        iframe = random.choice(language_links)
    else:
        iframe = random.choice(category_links)

    return render_template('language.html', iframe=iframe, language=language, category=category)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to retrieve posts with the given language **and** category:

```
@app.route("/<language>/<category>")
def mixin(language, category):
    links = []

    query = models.Post.select().where(
        (models.Post.language ** language) &
        (models.Post.category ** category))
    for contenido in query:
        links.append(contenido.content)

    iframe = random.choice(links)
    return render_template('language.html', iframe=iframe, language=language, category=category)
```

To get posts with the given language **or** category, you would write:

```
query = models.Post.select().where(
    (models.Post.language ** language) |  # note the "pipe" instead of "&"
    (models.Post.category ** category))
```

---

Also the "**" operators may be inefficient. Is there a reason you are not using "==" instead? If you need to be able to do case-insensitive matching you can do:

```
(fn.LOWER(models.Post.language) == language.lower())
```